# Импортировать библиотеку как приложение

Tags: android, java, android-studio

По [инструкции](http://youon.ru/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/ustanovka-admob-v-android-prilozhenie) для внедрения admob надо импортировать библиотеку как приложение:

> 2.1 Откройте Eclipse и импортируйте библиотеку как приложение по адресу:
>
> ПАПКА_С_SDK\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Как это сделать для android studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В SDK должен быть установлен Google Repository, Google Play services.  
Откройте build.gradle модуля приложения и добавьте в dependencies вот такое:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

Получиться должно так:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

После этого нажмите Sync Now справа вверху.

P. S. Версия может отличаться в зависимости от установленной у вас версии. У меня стоит последняя на данный момент (6.5.87).

Comment: У меня тоже стоит compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87' Почему то не обновляется она автоматически, ее в ручную всегда надо обновлять?